# Opencart 2.3 Latest Products Page товар отображаются один и тот-же на всех страницах

Tags: opencart

Нужно было сделать отдельную страницу с последними добавленными товарами, решил сделать по аналогии со страницей Акции (specials) продублировал файлы:

```
/catalog/controller/product/special.php
/catalog/language/YOURLANGUAGE/product/special.php
/catalog/view/theme/YOURTHEME/template/product/special.tpl
```

назвал их novinki, по примерам с других сайтов вставил и заменил где предлагали код.

Сейчас последний добавленный товар отображается правильно, но не отображается нужное количество и при нажатии на пагинацию, товар отображается один и тот-же, хотя на странице [Акции](http://test.cmski.ru/specials/) все работает правильно.

И как настроить seo url с /index.php?route=product/novinki на /novinki ? в настройках эта функция включена.

Что нужно заменить в коде, чтобы отображалось как мне нужно?

Opencart Version 2.3.0.2 (rs.6)
Модификаторы http://shot.qip.ru/00QPGK-6mqQ2hICc/ + Deadcow SEO

[Страница на сайте](http://test_.cmski_.ru/index.php?route=product/novinki)

Код:

```
class ControllerProductNovinki extends Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->load->language('product/novinki');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $this->load->model('tool/image');

    if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
        $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
    } else {
        $sort = 'p.sort_order';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
        $order = $this->request->get['order'];
    } else {
        $order = 'ASC';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
        $page = $this->request->get['page'];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
        $limit = (int)$this->request->get['limit'];
    } else {
        $limit = $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit');
    }

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
    );

    $url = '';

    if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
        $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
        $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
        $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
        $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
    }

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('product/novinki', $url)
    );

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    $data['text_empty'] = $this->language->get('text_empty');
    $data['text_quantity'] = $this->language->get('text_quantity');
    $data['text_manufacturer'] = $this->language->get('text_manufacturer');
    $data['text_model'] = $this->language->get('text_model');
    $data['text_price'] = $this->language->get('text_price');
    $data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');
    $data['text_points'] = $this->language->get('text_points');
    $data['text_compare'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_compare'), (isset($this->session->data['compare']) ? count($this->session->data['compare']) : 0));
    $data['text_sort'] = $this->language->get('text_sort');
    $data['text_limit'] = $this->language->get('text_limit');

    $data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');
    $data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
    $data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');
    $data['button_list'] = $this->language->get('button_list');
    $data['button_grid'] = $this->language->get('button_grid');
    $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

    $data['compare'] = $this->url->link('product/compare');

    $data['products'] = array();

    $filter_data = array(
        'sort'  => $sort,
        'order' => $order,
        'start' => ($page - 1) * $limit,
        'limit' => $limit
    );

    $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProductSpecials($filter_data);

    $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getLatestProducts($filter_data);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result['image']) {
            $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
        } else {
            $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
        }

        if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
            $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
        } else {
            $price = false;
        }

        if ((float)$result['special']) {
            $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
        } else {
            $special = false;
        }

        if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
            $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);
        } else {
            $tax = false;
        }

        if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
            $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
        } else {
            $rating = false;
        }

        $data['products'][] = array(
            'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
            'thumb'       => $image,
            'name'        => $result['name'],
            'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
            'price'       => $price,
            'special'     => $special,
            'tax'         => $tax,
            'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
            'rating'      => $result['rating'],
            'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
        );
    }

    $url = '';

    if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
        $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
    }

    $data['sorts'] = array();

    $data['sorts'][] = array(
        'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'),
        'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',
        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/novinki', 'sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC' . $url)
    );

    $data['sorts'][] = array(
        'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_asc'),
        'value' => 'pd.name-ASC',
        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/novinki', 'sort=pd.name&order=ASC' . $url)
    );

    $data['sorts'][] = array(
        'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_desc'),
        'value' => 'pd.name-DESC',
        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/novinki', 'sort=pd.name&order=DESC' . $url)
    );

    $data['sorts'][] = array(
        'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_asc'),
        'value' => 'ps.price-ASC',
        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/novinki', 'sort=ps.price&order=ASC' . $url)
    );

    $data['sorts'][] = array(
        'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_desc'),
        'value' => 'ps.price-DESC',
        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/novinki', 'sort=ps.price&order=DESC' . $url)
    );

    if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_desc'),
            'value' => 'rating-DESC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/novinki', 'sort=rating&order=DESC' . $url)
        );

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_asc'),
            'value' => 'rating-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/novinki', 'sort=rating&order=ASC' . $url)
        );
    }

    $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_asc'),
            'value' => 'p.model-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/novinki', 'sort=p.model&order=ASC' . $url)
    );

    $data['sorts'][] = array(
        'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_desc'),
        'value' => 'p.model-DESC',
        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/novinki', 'sort=p.model&order=DESC' . $url)
    );

    $url = '';

    if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
        $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
        $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
    }

    $data['limits'] = array();

    $limits = array_unique(array($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit'), 25, 50, 75, 100));

    sort($limits);

    foreach($limits as $value) {
        $data['limits'][] = array(
            'text'  => $value,
            'value' => $value,
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/novinki', $url . '&limit=' . $value)
        );
    }

    $url = '';

    if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
        $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
        $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
        $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
    }

    $pagination = new Pagination();
    $pagination->total = $product_total;
    $pagination->page = $page;
    $pagination->limit = $limit;
    $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/novinki', $url . '&page={page}');

    $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

    $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($product_total) ? (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($product_total - $limit)) ? $product_total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), $product_total, ceil($product_total / $limit));

    // http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html
    if ($page == 1) {
        $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/novinki', '', true), 'canonical');
    } elseif ($page == 2) {
        $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/novinki', '', true), 'prev');
    } else {я
        $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/novinki', 'page='. ($page - 1), true), 'prev');
    }

    if ($limit && ceil($product_total / $limit) > $page) {
        $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/novinki', 'page='. ($page + 1), true), 'next');
    }

    $data['sort'] = $sort;
    $data['order'] = $order;
    $data['limit'] = $limit;

    $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
    $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
    $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/novinki', $data));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPD:**

Вы, для получения общего количества товаров в `$product_total`, дёргаете модель за `getTotalProductSpecials()` и она вам честно отдаёт количество спешел_продактс. В свою очередь, метод `getLatestProducts()` не побходит для формирования категории с полноценной сортировкой/фильтрацией.

**ПО СЕМУ**: В моделе `catalog\model\catalog\product.php`, дублируйте метод `getProducts()`, назовите дубликат `getLatestProductsCategory()`, в нём замените:

```
 $sort_data = array(
        'pd.name',
        'p.model',
        'p.quantity',
        'p.price',
        'rating',
        'p.sort_order',
        'p.date_added'
    );

    if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
        if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC, LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
        } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
        } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.date_added') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY p.date_added";
        } else {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC, " . $data['sort'];
        }
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";
    };
```

на:

```
   $sort_data = array(
        'pd.name',
        'p.model',
        'p.quantity',
        'p.price',
        'rating',
        'p.sort_order',
    );

    $sql = " ORDER BY p.date_added DESC, "; 
    // добавляется мультисорт с обязательной сортировкой по дате (ORDER BY далее режутся)

    if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
        if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
            $sql .= " p.sort_order ASC, LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
        } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
            $sql .= " (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
        } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.date_added') {
            $sql .= " p.date_added";
        } else {
            $sql .= " p.sort_order ASC, " . $data['sort'];
        }
    } else {
        $sql .= " p.sort_order";
    }
```

Соответственно, в контроллере `ControllerProductNovinki`  замените:

```
$filter_data = array(
    'sort'  => $sort,
    'order' => $order,
    'start' => ($page - 1) * $limit,
    'limit' => $limit
);

$product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProductSpecials($filter_data);

$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getLatestProducts($filter_data);
```

на:

```
$filter_data = array(
    'sort'  => $sort,
    'order' => $order,
    'start' => ($page - 1) * $limit,
    'limit' => $limit
);

$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getLatestProductsCategory($filter_data);

$product_total = count($results);
```

**Касаемо ЧПУ** - если имеете доступ к бд, то сделайте так (опция seo url в настройках магазина должна быть check):
в базе найдите таблицу `ваш_префикс_url_alias` и добавьте в неё руками `query => product/novinki, keywor=> novinki`
или запросом

```
INSERT INTO `ваш_префикс_url_alias`(`query`, `keyword`) VALUES (`product/novinki`,`novinki`);
```

Comment: Это не помогло( для чпу тоже(

Comment: Я вам дал вариант на 200% рабочий. Очистите кеш модификаторов на всякий случай. seo url включён в настройках магазина?

Comment: Может я что то не так сделал, ссылка на страницу http://test.cmski.ru/index.php?route=product/novinki выводится только один товар, скрин кода http://shot.qip.ru/00QPGK-6mqQ2hICY/ сео урл заработал через некоторое время, в модификаторе кеш почистил, ссылка с какой страницы делал http://test.cmski.ru/specials/

Comment: чпу подтянулся, пагинация работает верно. остаётся запрос.Покажите листинг getLatestProducts()

Comment: И в  $filter_data = array(
        'sort'  => 'p.date_added',
        'order' => 'DESC',
И в $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data); поменяйте

Comment: так http://shot.qip.ru/00QPGK-4mqQ2hICZ/ ?

Comment: Листинг это показать функцию getLatestProducts нужно, это http://shot.qip.ru/00QPGK-4mqQ2hID0/ ?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать так, как я описал в последнем комменте.

Comment: Извините, я не совсем понял как именно, по этому и скинул скриншот, не понимаю в общем.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62554/discussion-between-kirill-korushkin-and-makissm).